# How to keep HTTP request from timing out, JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

Hi How should I go about preventing http request from timing out?

Thanks much

Comment: This question is unanswerable unless you tell us why the request is timing out.

Comment: If you really mean a http request, I guess you have to send back a page before the web browser times out.

Comment: What is timing out? The browser? Use AJAX or a loading page.

Comment: The browser on the client side timed out because the request take quite a bit of time to process. Is there anyway I can fix this? Thank you guys much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to prevent that the webbrowser times out a long running HTTP request?

You need to write *something* to the response, even though it's just a simple visualization of the progress. Or do the long-running task in a background thread instead of the HTTP request thread. Or optimize the long running task that it doesn't run inasanely long.

---

**Update**: as per the comments, you could create a background thread with help of [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and submit the long running task to it.

```
public class LongRunningTaskServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private ExecutorService executor;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // First gather necessary parameters for the background task (you shouldn't pass request/response to it!).
        String param1 = request.getParameter("param1");
        String param2 = request.getParameter("param2");

        // Then create the background task and submit it to the executor.
        executors.submit(new LongRunningTask(param1, param2));
        // It returns a Future, you can if necessary store it in session so that you can later check if it is finished and/or has returned a result.

        // Immediately display result.
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/result.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        executor.shutdownNow(); // Important! Pevent thread leaking.
    }

}
```

The `LongRunningTask` class has to implement [`Callable<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) or [`Runnable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html). Be careful with threads, do not remove the `destroy()` in above example.

#### See also:

- [The Java Tutorials - Concurrency - Executors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by "do the long-running task in a background thread instead of the HTTP request thread". That sounds really sensible... How exactly should I take that idea?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really clear. Though if you mean is, the session will not time out. Then set the session-timeout to 0 or less in web.xml.

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```